# Synchronize multiple thread of the same client in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, server

I made an email client which has two main threads: the first one is the one with the GUI and the second one is that which get executed in the background in a loop and that update the GUI if their new emails. I would like to synchronize these this thread and execute them one at  a time. On the server I manage them on this way:

```
public void initModel() throws IOException {
    contenutoTextArea.append("Waiting for connections\n");
    textarea.setText(contenutoTextArea.toString());
    s = new ServerSocket(5000);
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    new ThreadedEchoHandler(s);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }.start();
}

class ThreadedEchoHandler implements Runnable {

    private Socket incoming;

    private String nomeAccount = "";

    ThreadedEchoHandler(ServerSocket serv) throws IOException {
        incoming = serv.accept();
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run() {
        ....
    }
```

Does the JVM execute them on in time?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? What is it you want to know / what isn't working...?

Comment: I have a background thread which asks the send a string to the server and a lot of time I see that string in the process of the main thread. This means that the background thread interfere with the main one. So I would like to make this background thread to stop when the user does something on the client and then to resume when it finishes. I can't do it directly because I've the thread in a different class

Comment: "thread which asks the send a string", "I see that string in the process of the main thread" - these phrases are not clear, and so no one can answer you.

Comment: same advice as always (in questions with this account as well as in the  questions in your old account https://stackoverflow.com/users/9681974/jimbelushi2 ): please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.